# Initial value in Cauchy's problem properties?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i have this simple question :

let's have this Cauchy's problem , (with $f$ given and smooth):

$y'(t)=f(y(t))$ and $y(0)=y_0$ ,t>0,

is it true that when we have $y_0=0$ then the solution $y$ verify $y(t)=0$ $\forall t>0$  if yes how can we prove it .

(and if not true can someone give a counter-example)

thanks ....

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: i think it is true , well i found this example , $y'(t)=y^2(t)$ , and $y(0)=0$ then the book says that $y$ is zero everywhere so i wanted to know if it is true in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. What is true is that if $f(y_0)=0$, then $y(t)=y_0$ is a constant solution.

Try the modified example $y'=y^2-1$ which has constant solutions at $y_0=\pm 1$ but not at zero.

Comment: you said "" What is true is that if $f(y_0)=0$ then $y(t)=y_0$ is a constant solution."" this is exactly what i was searching !! can you tell me how to prove it??

Comment: Well, $y'(t)=0=f(y(t))$, so the differential equation is satisfied.

Comment: i don't see, what you want to tell me , here in your case there is only $f(y_0)=f(y(0))=y'(0)=0 $ that all what we have , doesn't it ? how did you get  $y'(t)=0$ for all t

Comment: in general case i mean not in this example , above

Comment: The derivative of a constant is constant zero.

Comment: yes i know , but here you proved it only for t=0, how about t>0

Comment: No, this is valid everywhere since it is constant, nothing changes.